# WSO2 not working after changing certificates

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have wso2 Identity server in my TEST environment. Team has been using it for some months and lot of users and roles are created. Recently we have got CA certificates and installed it. After that we cant add users saying the problem Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name. Looks like new certificate is the problem

1)I have my MySQL database in AWS Cloud. Could anything with the database cause problem? 
2) If i clear all the tables for WSO2 , will WSO2 work again? If so , which are all the tables to clear.

Suggest any other solutions

Comment: did you import the certificates the keystore? and update the keystore path and key alias and passwords in carbon.xml

Comment: Yes.I did. I used the same password as wso2carbon..so didnt have to change password

Comment: What can i do to verify things?